# HTML5 Canvas rendering oddly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rendering, typeerror

I'm in the process of learning HTML5 (and OO Javascript) and am trying to make a simple game engine but rendering to canvas works under very odd conditions. [Here](http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/~aalksne/valGame/) is a link to the page and here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load()
        {
            var game = new Game();
            game.start();   
        }
    </script>
    <title>Game</title>
    <style>
        canvas
        {
            outline:0;
            border:1px solid #000;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <canvas id='c'></canvas>

    <script src="classes/Tuple.js"></script>
    <script src="classes/Rect.js"></script>
    <script src="classes/Sprite.js"></script>
    <script src="classes/Game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When first loaded, it will give an **NS_ERROR_DOM_TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR** Exception in Firefox 11.0 and a **TypeError** Exception in Chrome 18.0. To make it work:

## Firefox 11.0

- select the URL in the address bar and manually hit enter OR
- click the refresh button OR
- press F5.

## Chrome 18.0

- select the URL in the address bar and manually hit enter OR
- click the refresh button OR
- press F5 OR
- press Shift/Ctrl + F5.

**What I suspect** - Just a guess but it seems like one or more of the .js files is not available/ready by the time it is called during the first page load. Having stepped through it a couple of times in Firebug it seems that the sprite images never get loaded on the first page request.

Perhaps some of the .js files are still being downloaded as the instantiation to Game() is being made, then cached, and are only all available by the second page load?

Any ideas? I'd be grateful for your take on it, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I've made Game.js the first of the four includes but I seem to be getting the same behavior (I force refreshed so I'm not going off of a cached copy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your files locally and did some testing. It looks to me like it's not your JavaScript files that are unavailable, but your sprite.

You're not loading the PNG until you call `Game.start`.  When you do:

```
roadSpritesheetImage.src = "assets/sprites/player/playerSpriteSheet.png";
```

This begins an asynchronous download of the image. The rest of the code is executed before the image has fully loaded, so when you're slicing the image, you're slicing it as if the src attribute were null.

This is why you're able to hit refresh and everything works as expected... the image is cached.

You can sort of preempt the loading of your sprite by adding an image tag just before the canvas:

```
<img src="assets/sprites/player/playerSpriteSheet.png" style="display:none;" />
```

This would work because the body load event isn't fired until content (including images) is fully loaded (I believe, I'd have to look this up).  Then, if you assign this image to `img.src`, you will be referencing the cached image.

Alternatively, you could bind the rest of the game functionality to `img.onload`. For example:

```
self.loadSprites = function()
{
    var roadSpritesheetImage = new Image();     
    roadSpritesheetImage.onload = function() { 
        self.entities.push(new Sprite("testTile", 
            roadSpritesheetImage, 
            new Tuple(16, 16), 
            new Rect(0, 0, 32, 16)));
        self.run();
    };

    roadSpritesheetImage.src = "assets/sprites/player/playerSpriteSheet.png";
};

self.run = function() {
    var drawSuccessful = false;
    drawSuccessful = self.entities[0].draw(self.context);
    self.entities[0].nextFrame();

    //if we managed to draw the Sprite successfully without any raised exceptions
    if(drawSuccessful) {
        setTimeout(self.run, 300);
    } else { alert("stopping execution of the game."); }
};

self.start = function()
{
    self.loadSprites();
};
```

Doing this is a bit cleaner and it would guarantee you don't have any race conditions with your resources.

I had a similar issue with a jQuery plugin I created to draw an N-puzzle from a source image.  I found [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) extremely useful at the time, although I ended up using sliced divs instead of a canvas.

Comment: That's great thank you! After looking at the loading process in the Chrome Timeline feature I was starting to suspect the same thing.

However I just assumed that when you declare a new Image() object, it just waits until the image is loaded until proceeding. I see now that that's not the case.

This is a new account so I don't have enough reputation to upvote your post but when I do I will. Thanks again, you've saved me hours of confusion!

Comment: @AlexAlksne, you can mark it as an answer. Now you need to take into account when loading 2+ sprites, `self.run()` should not be call until all of them are loaded.

Comment: @AlexAlksne no problem. In a case like this, it can be difficult to catch the loading times... especially when your sprite is only 4K.

Comment: @JimSchubert so then is it safe to assume that you should not rely on JS to load resources on time? Should I have a policy of, whenever loading any kind of resource (audio/video/etc.), to always pause execution by defining an onLoad function for that resource and calling self.run after it completes?

Comment: @AlexAlksne You would have to provide some way to ensure your resources are available before they're accessed in code. You could do some ugly onload chaining or load them in the DOM. You could use an [AssetManager](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/games/assetmanager/) to preload everything and maybe have a [CSS Animation](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#css-animation) to indicate loading status...

Comment: @Alexander good point, thank you! But I have a question, if the onLoad() method is called only after the image has finished loading, isn't it possible for the main program to attempt to use the image before onLoad() has been executed? Is there a way to halt all execution of the main program until onLoad completes?